# Detecting when a user stops typing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, io, event-handling

I wanted to detect when a user stops typing. I encountered this answer from SO (Not the selected answer, but the second one which seem to be better):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926782/17746636

But I edited it slightly to use `keydown` instead of `keyup`. Also the target is `window` for my example (I need to detect any key strokes on the window):

```js
let typingTimer;
let doneTypingInterval = 1000;

window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

function doneTyping() {
  console.log("Stopped typing");
}
```

I changed from `keyup` to `keydown` because there might be cases where a user can click on another window while typing, and then the timeout will never be released. Using `keydown` seem to work better and ensures that if a user is typing and then clicks on another window, then it will trigger the `doneTyping` function

Answer (score 4):

Structurally, there is nothing wrong with the approach.

- You could consider `const` for `doneTypingInterval`, I would put a comment that this is in milliseconds
- I would create a self-executing function to hide `typingTimer` from the global scope.

  - `doneTypingInterval` could then be a parameter or remain a constant
  - `doneTyping` could be a local function, or could be a parameter
- I am not the biggest fan of anonymous functions, you could consider naming it

```js
function doneTyping() {
  console.log("Stopped typing");
}

(function setupTypingDetection(element, maximumDelayBetweenKeystrokes, postTypingFunction) {
  let typingTimer;

  element.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(postTypingFunction, maximumDelayBetweenKeystrokes);
  });
})(window, 1000, doneTyping);
```

Comment: Instead of a comment, you could rename `doneTypingInterval` to something that includes the unit, such as `maxIdleMilliseconds` or something.

Answer (score 2):

> ```js
> let typingTimer;
> let doneTypingInterval = 1000;
>
> window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
>   clearTimeout(typingTimer);
>   typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
> });
> ```

If you need this behaviour more than once it might be a good idea to abstract the general idea of delayed execution and resetting the timer when called early.

```js
function fnDelay(fn, msDelay) {
  let timeoutID;
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(fn, msDelay, ...args);
  };
}
```

This abstraction would allow you to transform your code into:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', fnDelay(doneTypeing, 1000));

function doneTyping() {
  console.log("Stopped typing");
}
```

ps. `fnDelay` is probably not the best name for this function, but I currently can't come up with a better one.

---

I personally also like to define time units as constants.

```js
//           [------- unit definition ------] [--------- alias ---------]
export const MILLISECOND =    1             , MILLISECONDS = MILLISECOND;
export const SECOND      = 1000*MILLISECONDS, SECONDS      = SECOND     ;
export const MINUTE      =   60*SECONDS     , MINUTES      = MINUTE     ;
export const HOUR        =   60*MINUTES     , HOURS        = HOUR       ;
export const DAY         =   24*HOURS       , DAYS         = DAY        ;
export const WEEK        =    7*DAYS        , WEEKS        = WEEK       ;
```

This might seem overkill, but these constants are used quite often. I find `fnDelay(doneTypeing, 1*SECOND)` more expressive/readable than `fnDelay(doneTypeing, 1000)`.